# To enable commit button in github

Tags: github

My commit button is not getting enabled after editing Readme file in github.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the commit button is not enabled is because you are trying to commit to the `master` branch of the repo, **which is protected from making direct commits/push**. Only those who have access to make direct commits to `master` can do that, and you might not have that access. Hence you need to select the second option there to create a new branch to make the commit and create a pull request to the master branch, or get access to directly contribute to that branch.

The branch protection is to ensure that collaborators don't directly push or make commits to the particular branch or delete it, and also allows enabling status checks or required reviews. You can read more about GitHub's branch protection [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-protected-branches).